# android sending pictures from cam via socket

Tags: android, sockets, camera2

I transmit the images frame-by-frame from the camera via the socket after clicking on the form. I do not understand how to make an uninterrupted transfer of images after clicking on the form. Tried to put in a cycle, but in this case the image displayed on the form hangs. How to do it right? Here is the code with which I work.

```
    /**
     * Called when the user clicks on our {@code SurfaceView}, which has ID {@code mainSurfaceView}
     * as defined in the {@code mainactivity.xml} layout file. <p>Captures a full-resolution image
     * and saves it to permanent storage.</p>
     */


    public void onClickOnSurfaceView(View v) {
        if (mCaptureSession != null) {
            try {
                CaptureRequest.Builder requester =
                        mCamera.createCaptureRequest(mCamera.TEMPLATE_STILL_CAPTURE);
                requester.addTarget(mCaptureBuffer.getSurface());
                try {
                    // This handler can be null because we aren't actually attaching any callback
                    mCaptureSession.capture(requester.build(), /*listener*/null, /*handler*/null);
                } catch (CameraAccessException ex) {
                    Log.e(TAG, "Failed to file actual capture request", ex);
                }
            } catch (CameraAccessException ex) {
                Log.e(TAG, "Failed to build actual capture request", ex);
            }
        } else {
            Log.e(TAG, "User attempted to perform a capture outside our session");
        }
        // Control flow continues in mImageCaptureListener.onImageAvailable()

    }

    /**
     * Callbacks invoked upon state changes in our {@code SurfaceView}.
     */
    final SurfaceHolder.Callback mSurfaceHolderCallback = new SurfaceHolder.Callback() {
        /** The camera device to use, or null if we haven't yet set a fixed surface size. */
        private String mCameraId;
        /** Whether we received a change callback after setting our fixed surface size. */
        private boolean mGotSecondCallback;

        @Override
        public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
            // This is called every time the surface returns to the foreground
            Log.i(TAG, "Surface created");
            mCameraId = null;
            mGotSecondCallback = false;
        }

        @Override
        public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
            Log.i(TAG, "Surface destroyed");
            holder.removeCallback(this);
            // We don't stop receiving callbacks forever because onResume() will reattach us
        }

        @Override
        public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int width, int height) {
            // On the first invocation, width and height were automatically set to the view's size
            if (mCameraId == null) {
                // Find the device's back-facing camera and set the destination buffer sizes
                try {
                    for (String cameraId : mCameraManager.getCameraIdList()) {
                        CameraCharacteristics cameraCharacteristics =
                                mCameraManager.getCameraCharacteristics(cameraId);
                        if (cameraCharacteristics.get(cameraCharacteristics.LENS_FACING) ==
                                CameraCharacteristics.LENS_FACING_BACK) {
                            Log.i(TAG, "Found a back-facing camera");
                            StreamConfigurationMap info = cameraCharacteristics
                                    .get(CameraCharacteristics.SCALER_STREAM_CONFIGURATION_MAP);
                            // Bigger is better when it comes to saving our image
                            Size largestSize = Collections.max(
                                    Arrays.asList(info.getOutputSizes(ImageFormat.JPEG)),
                                    new CompareSizesByArea());
                            // Prepare an ImageReader in case the user wants to capture images
                            Log.i(TAG, "Capture size: " + largestSize);
                            mCaptureBuffer = ImageReader.newInstance(640,
                                    480, ImageFormat.JPEG, /*maxImages*/2);
                            mCaptureBuffer.setOnImageAvailableListener(
                                    mImageCaptureListener, mBackgroundHandler);
                            Log.i(TAG, "SurfaceView size: " +
                                    mSurfaceView.getWidth() + 'x' + mSurfaceView.getHeight());
                            Size optimalSize = chooseBigEnoughSize(
                                    info.getOutputSizes(SurfaceHolder.class), width, height);
                            // Set the SurfaceHolder to use the camera's largest supported size
                            Log.i(TAG, "Preview size: " + optimalSize);
                            SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder = mSurfaceView.getHolder();
                            surfaceHolder.setFixedSize(optimalSize.getWidth(),
                                    optimalSize.getHeight());
                            mCameraId = cameraId;
                            return;
                        }
                    }
                } catch (CameraAccessException ex) {
                    Log.e(TAG, "Unable to list cameras", ex);
                }
                Log.e(TAG, "Didn't find any back-facing cameras");
                // This is the second time the method is being invoked: our size change is complete
            } else if (!mGotSecondCallback) {
                if (mCamera != null) {
                    Log.e(TAG, "Aborting camera open because it hadn't been closed");
                    return;
                }
                // Open the camera device
                try {
                    mCameraManager.openCamera(mCameraId, mCameraStateCallback,
                            mBackgroundHandler);
                } catch (CameraAccessException ex) {
                    Log.e(TAG, "Failed to configure output surface", ex);
                }
                mGotSecondCallback = true;
                // Control flow continues in mCameraStateCallback.onOpened()
            }
        }
    };
    /**
     * Calledbacks invoked upon state changes in our {@code CameraDevice}. <p>These are run on
     * {@code mBackgroundThread}.</p>
     */
    final CameraDevice.StateCallback mCameraStateCallback =
            new CameraDevice.StateCallback() {
                @Override
                public void onOpened(CameraDevice camera) {
                    Log.i(TAG, "Successfully opened camera");
                    mCamera = camera;
                    try {
                            List<Surface> outputs = Arrays.asList(
                                    mSurfaceView.getHolder().getSurface(), mCaptureBuffer.getSurface());
                            camera.createCaptureSession(outputs, mCaptureSessionListener,
                                    mBackgroundHandler);
                    } catch (CameraAccessException ex) {
                        Log.e(TAG, "Failed to create a capture session", ex);
                    }
                    // Control flow continues in mCaptureSessionListener.onConfigured()
                }

                @Override
                public void onDisconnected(CameraDevice camera) {
                    Log.e(TAG, "Camera was disconnected");
                }

                @Override
                public void onError(CameraDevice camera, int error) {
                    Log.e(TAG, "State error on device '" + camera.getId() + "': code " + error);
                }
            };
    /**
     * Callbacks invoked upon state changes in our {@code CameraCaptureSession}. <p>These are run on
     * {@code mBackgroundThread}.</p>
     */
    final CameraCaptureSession.StateCallback mCaptureSessionListener =
            new CameraCaptureSession.StateCallback() {
                @Override
                public void onConfigured(CameraCaptureSession session) {
                    Log.i(TAG, "Finished configuring camera outputs");
                    mCaptureSession = session;
                    SurfaceHolder holder = mSurfaceView.getHolder();
                    if (holder != null) {
                        try {
                            // Build a request for preview footage
                            CaptureRequest.Builder requestBuilder =
                                    mCamera.createCaptureRequest(mCamera.TEMPLATE_PREVIEW);
                            requestBuilder.addTarget(holder.getSurface());
                            CaptureRequest previewRequest = requestBuilder.build();
                            // Start displaying preview images
                            try {
                                session.setRepeatingRequest(previewRequest, /*listener*/null,
                                /*handler*/null);
                            } catch (CameraAccessException ex) {
                                Log.e(TAG, "Failed to make repeating preview request", ex);
                            }
                        } catch (CameraAccessException ex) {
                            Log.e(TAG, "Failed to build preview request", ex);
                        }
                    } else {
                        Log.e(TAG, "Holder didn't exist when trying to formulate preview request");
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void onClosed(CameraCaptureSession session) {
                    mCaptureSession = null;
                }

                @Override
                public void onConfigureFailed(CameraCaptureSession session) {
                    Log.e(TAG, "Configuration error on device '" + mCamera.getId());
                }
            };
    /**
     * Callback invoked when we've received a JPEG image from the camera.
     */
    final ImageReader.OnImageAvailableListener mImageCaptureListener =
            new ImageReader.OnImageAvailableListener() {
                @Override
                public void onImageAvailable(ImageReader reader) {
                    // Save the image once we get a chance
                        mBackgroundHandler.post(new CapturedImageSaver(reader.acquireNextImage()));
                }
            };

    static class CapturedImageSaver implements Runnable {
        /**
         * The image to save.
         */
        private Image mCapture;

        public CapturedImageSaver(Image capture) {
            mCapture = capture;
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                // Choose an unused filename under the Pictures/ directory
                File file = File.createTempFile(CAPTURE_FILENAME_PREFIX, ".jpg",
                        Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(
                                Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES));
                try (FileOutputStream ostream = new FileOutputStream(file)) {
                    Log.i(TAG, "Retrieved image is" +
                            (mCapture.getFormat() == ImageFormat.JPEG ? "" : "n't") + " a JPEG");
                    ByteBuffer buffer = mCapture.getPlanes()[0].getBuffer();
                    Log.i(TAG, "Captured image size: " +
                            mCapture.getWidth() + 'x' + mCapture.getHeight());
                    // Write the image out to the chosen file
                    byte[] jpeg = new byte[buffer.remaining()];
                    buffer.get(jpeg);
                    //ostream.write(jpeg);
                    //send image via socket
                    System.out.println(SERVER_IP);
                    InetAddress serverAddr = InetAddress.getByName(SERVER_IP);
                    System.out.println("Created serverAddr " + SERVER_IP);
                    Socket socket = new Socket(serverAddr, SERVER_PORT);
                    System.out.println("Socket created..");
                    System.out.println(mCapture.getWidth() + "^" + mCapture.getHeight());

                    try (DataOutputStream dOut = new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream())) {
                        dOut.writeInt(jpeg.length);
                        dOut.write(jpeg);
                        dOut.flush();
                    }
                } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
                    Log.e(TAG, "Unable to open output file for writing", ex);
                } catch (IOException ex) {
                    Log.e(TAG, "Failed to write the image to the output file", ex);
                }
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                Log.e(TAG, "Unable to create a new output file", ex);
            } finally {
                mCapture.close();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

a bit remade code. The function added a call to receive a snapshot on the timer every 170 milliseconds. If I set the time less than the specified, the interface hangs ... Someone can tell me how to do it right? Now I have 5.88 frames per second. I would like to achieve at least 15 frames per second.

```
public void onClickOnSurfaceView(View v) {
        int i = 0;

        Timer myTimer = new Timer(); // Создаем таймер
        final Handler uiHandler = new Handler();
        myTimer.schedule(new TimerTask() { // Определяем задачу
            @Override
            public void run() {
                uiHandler.post(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        if (mCaptureSession != null) {
                            //while(true){
                            try {
                                CaptureRequest.Builder requester =
                                        mCamera.createCaptureRequest(mCamera.TEMPLATE_STILL_CAPTURE);
                                requester.addTarget(mCaptureBuffer.getSurface());
                                //while(i<20) {
                                try {
                                    // This handler can be null because we aren't actually attaching any callback

                                    mCaptureSession.capture(requester.build(), /*listener*/null, /*handler*/null);
                                } catch (CameraAccessException ex) {
                                    Log.e(TAG, "Failed to file actual capture request", ex);
                                }
                                //}
                            } catch (CameraAccessException ex) {
                                Log.e(TAG, "Failed to build actual capture request", ex);
                            }
                            //}
                        } else {
                            Log.e(TAG, "User attempted to perform a capture outside our session");
                        }
                    }
                });
            };
        }, 0L, 1L * 180); // интервал - 500 миллисекунд, 0 миллисекунд до первого запуска.

        // Control flow continues in mImageCaptureListener.onImageAvailable()

    }
```

I could not solve the problem in this way, so I proceeded as follows: at the time when I needed to transfer the image, I got the current picture from the SurfaceView (screenshot) and sent it through the socket.

Comment: Much to much code. You should only post relevant code. Please clean up.

Comment: Hi, take a look at [mcve] and clean up the code a bit

Comment: @Passer By i cleaned up code a bit. I would clean more, but I do not yet understand what kind of fragment needs to be worked out.